# How to dynamic set the properties of service in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, singleton

I using angular 7 and I have service like:

```
@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {

 private variable: Variable[];
 url = 'http://127.0.0.1:4000/api/variable'; //I want make this as parameter when I initialize the service.
 async createDb() {
 if (this.variable.length > 0) {
  return this.variable;
 } else {
  this.variable = await this.getdata();
 }
 }

 async getdata() {
  return await axios.get(this.url).then(res => res.data)
  .catch(err => { console.log(err); return []; });
 }

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

I want to change the url in config file or config.js and read this config file to change the url path:

like I want to change:

```
constructor(private url: string){
}
```

how to set in Angular7 and register this service variable in Angular framework?

Comment: read about injectionTokens

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments

Answer (score 0):

If i get it Right, you want to send data from component to service and set it in a variable.

you can inject your service in your component in this way

```
import { CommonService } from './../common.service';
constructor(public commonService:CommonService ){}
```

and create a function is your service which requires a parameter

```
public myvar:any;
setData(param){
    this.myvar  = param;
}
```

and call it from component as

```
this.commonService.setData("parameter");
```